# Get a node as raw XML in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

Provided I have an XML structure:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>aaa</c>
    <d a="42"/>
  </b>
</a>
```

I want to get the `b`-node as the original XML String:

```
<b>
  <c>aaa</c>
  <d a="42"/>
</b>
```

I tried using `XmlSlurper.text()`, but it returns only the `aaa`.

Is it possible to yield the raw XML from the node, without re-creating it with XmlBuilder?

UPDATE

I ended up using the following:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()
XmlNodePrinter p = new XmlNodePrinter( new IndentPrinter( sw, '', false, false ), "'" )
p.namespaceAware = false
node.children().each p.&print

println sw
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`XmlUtil.serialize()`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/XmlUtil.html#serialize(groovy.util.Node)):

```
import groovy.xml.*
def xmlString = '''<a>
  <b>
    <c>aaa</c>
    <d a="42"/>
  </b>
</a>'''
def bNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString).b

def bXML = XmlUtil.serialize(bNode)

println(bXML)
```